# WP HTML Templates - Any way to get bloginfo() or the path to the theme folder?

Tags: themes, html, bloginfo

So in our new architecture for themes, we want to use Gutenberg themes with html templates.

Problem is, when we need to call anything from the theme folder, we have to use the full URL. So if the folder name would be to change for any reason (and we might change it) well, every image loaded from the template breaks.

In PHP, you can simply run the function `bloginfo()` to get that. But is there the same thing in HTML templates?

Example:

```
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"top","tagName":"div","align":"full","className":"l-top","layout":{"inherit":true}} /-->
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"header","tagName":"header","align":"full","className":"l-header","layout":{"inherit":true}} /-->
<!-- wp:group {"tagName":"main","align":"full", "className":"l-main t-page", "layout":{"inherit":true}} -->
<main class="wp-block-group alignfull l-main t-page">

    <!-- wp:cover {
        "url":"/wp-content/themes/base-theme/assets/img/default-cover.jpg",
        "dimRatio":0,
        "isDark":false,
        "align":"full",
    } -->
    <div class="wp-block-cover alignfull is-light is-style-title-banner">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="wp-block-cover__background has-background-dim-0 has-background-dim"></span>
        <img class="wp-block-cover__image-background" alt="" src="/wp-content/themes/base-theme/assets/img/default-cover.jpg" data-object-fit="cover"/>
        <div class="wp-block-cover__inner-container">
            <!-- wp:post-title {"level":1} /-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /wp:cover -->
    <!-- wp:yoast-seo/breadcrumbs /-->
    <!-- wp:post-content {"className":"wp-container__inner","layout":{"inherit":true}} /-->

</main>
<!-- /wp:group -->
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"footer","tagName":"footer","align":"full","layout":{"inherit":true}} /-->
```

Comment: What about putting the assets in a separate folder from the theme, like on the root, and just call `/assets/img/default-cover.jpg`, for ex.

Comment: Because that doesnt respect the WP structure. Things related to the theme should be in the theme and nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this isn't possible, twentytwentytwo works around this by registering patterns in a subfolder then using a pattern block.

This way they can define patterns in PHP then use the functions. This is how they show the bird in the header and include localised strings.